Next.JS: Date is based on the server's local time in a client component
Context
When I declare const now = new Date() inside a component marked with 'use client' the date is logged as a UTC date while the client is in Pacific Time. I am declaring the variable outside of the component.
Issue
When I interact with the component on the client to cause a re-render, the value of the date variable changes to the client's timezone, as if this code outside of the component is being run again. I would like to understand why this is. I thought this code would only run again on a page reload. My problem is that I have a dynamic src which only displays the correct image when I interact with the component. When I refresh the page after a day, the old image with the previous day's date is displayed.
Question
I understand that this variable is being initialized on the server at first, but I don't understand why the code outside of the component is being run on the client on the first re-render of the component.
I would like to know more about what was happening. What is the life cycle of a component marked with 'use client'? Is the entire file run on the server first and then again on the client after the first interaction?
Update
I moved the declaration inside the component and added some logic to make sure the timezone is correct regardless of where the date is declared. The image from the previous day is still being shown after a refresh even though the src props contains a different date and a no-cache cache control header is present. Still it's only when I cycle the image back and forth that the correct image displays. Is the old component rendering after a refresh even though the src state is being reset to the current date? My src looks like this: https://website.com/data/${date}.png and date is a state variable.

Because on server, the code will run during ssr, and the date will be in the server's timezone (typically UTC in default if not configured).
and on client, React re-renders the component, this causes const now = new Date() to be executed on the client too, resulting in a date in the client's timezone (Pacific Time in your case).

Added some more context. I thought I had solved my issue by fixing the dates but there is still a rendering issue where my component is not updating on a page refresh.

what would be the solution though ?

Disabling prerendering as mentioned in the NextJS docs helped: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#solution-2-disabling-ssr-on-specific-components
In the parent component (it can be a server component) you import the component using next/dynamic and disable prerendering for this component. So make sure you isolate only the date time inside this component and render that.
The solution leads to a slight flickering upon page load and it may hurt SEO if you care about that.
Here is another solution which involves wrapping your component in Suspense tags: https://francoisbest.com/posts/2023/displaying-local-times-in-nextjs
It also causes a little bit of flickering but is less instrusive.
